# dynamically add data by prompting the user everytime in android

Tags: android

i have an edit-text field to contain full postal addresses. Now i want to prompt the user if he wants to enter more addresses using an `AlertDialog` on click of a button. If yes, the allow him to enter more values, if not the go to main activity. how do i do it using `AlertDialog` and `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Post your code for more clarification. If you are just want to show an AlertDialog and finish() your Activity on cancel then you will find tons of direct code from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the below code would be of help.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to enter more addresses!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, make the user enter more addresses

                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```